# Moving a function from code behind to Business Logic Layer Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, business-logic-layer

I am using `ASP.NET Web Forms/C#`.

I am having this function in my `code behind` which fills Cities `DropDownList` based on the State `DropDownList` selection.

Here is my function.

```
public void CityFill(int index,int id)
        {
            //This function calls GetCities method which will get all cities of a state.
            var city = CustomerBLL.GetCities(index);



            //If id=0 then clear all dropdown before filling
            //or else they get appended.
            if (id == 0)
            {
                NewCustomerddlResidentialCity.Items.Clear();
                NewCustomerddlOfficeCity.Items.Clear();
                NewCustomerddlNativeCity.Items.Clear();
                NewCustomerddlNomineeCity.Items.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                //If 1 then clear residential city
                if(id==1)
                    NewCustomerddlResidentialCity.Items.Clear();

                //If 2 then clear Office city.
                if(id==2)
                    NewCustomerddlOfficeCity.Items.Clear();

                //If id=3 then clear Native City.
                if(id==3)
                    NewCustomerddlNativeCity.Items.Clear();

                //If id=4 then clear Nominee City
                if(id==4)
                    NewCustomerddlNomineeCity.Items.Clear();
            }

            //Loop through all the cities in st object
            foreach (var c in city)
            {
                //If id=0 then fill all dropdowns
                if (id == 0)
                {
                    NewCustomerddlResidentialCity.Items.Add(c.city_name.Trim());
                    NewCustomerddlOfficeCity.Items.Add(c.city_name.Trim());
                    NewCustomerddlNativeCity.Items.Add(c.city_name.Trim());
                    NewCustomerddlNomineeCity.Items.Add(c.city_name.Trim());
                }
                else
                {
                    //If 1 then fill Res City
                    if(id==1)
                    NewCustomerddlResidentialCity.Items.Add(c.city_name.Trim());

                    //If 2 then fill Off City
                    if(id==2)
                    NewCustomerddlOfficeCity.Items.Add(c.city_name.Trim());

                    //If 3 then fill nat city
                    if(id==3)
                    NewCustomerddlNativeCity.Items.Add(c.city_name.Trim());

                    //If 4 then fill nominee city
                    if(id==4)
                    NewCustomerddlNomineeCity.Items.Add(c.city_name.Trim());

                }
            }
        }
```

The arguments passed to the function are index and id.
index is `SelectedIndex` of State `DropDownList`.
id is which City `DropDownList` needs to be filled.

Here is BLL class

```
namespace CwizBankApp
{
    public class CustomerBLL
    {
        public IList<mem_city> GetCities(int index)
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var city = db.mem_cities.Where(c => c.state_id.Equals(index)).ToList();
                return city;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to move the function from code behind to BLL class.

How do I go about this.

Can anyone help me out with this?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You shouldn't (can't) perform ui operation from the bll class. What is wrong with your code ?

Comment: @SteveB This code is working , so do you recommend that it should be used in code behind only?Is it ok?

Comment: Each layer have its responsibility. The BLL layer should handle the business logic, the DAL data access and UI the presentation. In this case, the code you are showing is, if I understand correctly, a way to setup UI basing on some business value. In this case, I think it's UI job, so your code looks like OK in my case.

Comment: @SteveB Basically I have 4 ddl for state and city ie Residential,Office,Native,Nominal and on change of state ddl , I am filling corresponding city.I hope it is a bit clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not to perform that in the BLL Class.  DON'T FORCE IT to BLL as is designed to seperate the data access logic from the presentation logic.

Comment: So what I am doing right now in code behind is fine , what do you think?Thanks.

Comment: yes.. that is correct. You can optimize that in code behind part itself.